# Cannot enable Flow Control on Cisco Nexus 3048

Tags: cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os, nx-os

I've a pair of Nexus 3048 running NXOS version 7.0(3)I2(2d) and I can't enable flow control on ethernet interfaces.

When issuing the command: `flowcontrol receive on` it returns with:

> ERROR: This CLI is not supported on n3k platform

How to enable flowcontrol on Nexus interfaces?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, link-level flowcontrol (LLFC) is not supported on the Nexus 3000 and 3100 series. It is supported on the Nexus 3500 series and Nexus 9000.

As an alternative, you could possibly implement PFC instead, cfr. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3000/sw/qos/7x/b_3k_QoS_Config_7x/b_3k_QoS_Config_7x_chapter_011.html

Comment: Could you elaborate more, hertitu? Reading the documentation the PFC needs a CoS value to match and apply the classification. What if I don't have pre-marked packages? I simply can't use Flow Control? My main goal is to get lossless, or some kind of, iSCSI.